# Lerna publish : determine published generated version number

Tags: javascript, lerna, npm-publish

When running lerna publish within our pipeline like so :

`lerna publish --yes --force-publish=* --canary --preid 2760 --registry`

Is there a way of getting the actual published version of the artifact.

One solution I can think of is trying to parse the response from that publish call, which outputs this :

```
lerna notice cli v3.13.1
lerna info ci enabled
lerna info canary enabled
lerna WARN force-publish all packages
lerna info Assuming all packages changed

Found 1 package to publish:
 - @xxx/xxx-xxx => 3.0.23-2760.5+175c890
```

Anyone have a more elegant solution?

Comment: There is work being done on a possible solution: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/pull/2653